# Calling multiple functions to generate textboxes on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling two separate functions to generate dynamic textboxes one of the function works fine whereas other doesn't work though  the code for generating textboxes is same except the variables names and label names. Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong and how can i figure out this ?

this is the function which is not working.

```
           var C = 3;
       var matrixArray = ["question", "mrank"];

       $("#addMatrix").click(function () {
         for(var j = 0; j < matrixArray.length; j++){
            createMatrixInput(MatrixArray[j]);
         }
         C++;
       });
function createMatrixInput(l){
            var tb_Div = $('#TextBoxes');
            var mstr = '<div class="control-group">';
            mstr += '<label class="control-label">' + l + " " + C + '</label>';
            mstr += '<div class="controls">';
            mstr += '<input type="text" id="' + l + '_' + C + '" name="'+ l +'_' + C + '" />';
            mstr += '</div>';
            mstr += '</div>';
            tb_Div.append(mstr);
        };
```

this is my jsfiddle with complete code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qqqyC/2/

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems. The button id is addmatrix and the array is matrixArray, not MatrixArray. The method should look like:

```
$("#addmatrix").click(function () {
    for(var j = 0; j < matrixArray.length; j++){
        createMatrixInput(matrixArray[j]);
        C++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh that's the good catch man. Case sensitivity is crazy. So now its clear we can call as many as functions on same page without any issues, its great.

Comment: nice, two case sensitive mistakes =p i've spotted only one haha :p

Answer (score 1):

I've spotted a error in your `JSFiddle` see the id of your button "matrix button" it is `addmatrix` and you are binding the `onClick` event to `addMatrix` and javascript event binding via `ID` is case sensitive, so the event will not be bind.

Maybe this will solve your whole problem, because it was preventing to execute the click event.

Comment: Once the event click it will generate two textboxes as I am passing l as a parameter in CreateMatrixInput function. Though same function I am using and its works fine if you have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/qqqyC/1/

Comment: Still same no success.